# Including a <form> inside a <section> in HTML5

Tags: html

Is it possible to add a `<form>` inside `<section>` in HTML5? Pointers to examples of usage of `<form>` inside `<section>` will be very useful as i'm not able to do the same..

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly valid to have `<form>` inside `<section>`. You can use `<section>` just like you'd use a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Example:

```
<section>
    <form>
        <input name="first_name" />
        <input type="submit" />
    <form>
</section>
```

If you're using a version of Internet Explorer prior to v9, you need to use [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make HTML5 elements like `<section>` work at all.